# What relay is needed?

Tags: low-voltage

I would like to use a thermopile to activate a 110 relay to turn on a fan.
What relay would be needed?

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information to help you. Also, please take the tour so you'll know how to best contribute here:   https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Century-BNQ-T7B-Digital-Cooling-Controller/dp/B01LZV591B  Maybe this?

Comment: Can you use a TC thermocouple to activate a relay? Yes but there will need to be some control electronics to provide the set point based on the output voltage of the TC. You might want to look into micro controllers like an Adriano or other programmable type of controller. The basic kit and an add on board will make this quite simple project with code already out there to make exactly what you want. This way you could set up for cooling or heating even create PID loops and other controls if you want to have more precise control of your project or room

Comment: Thanks Ed, found what I was looking for.